# Index of Nilpotence for modular groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, nilpotence

Why does $\mathbb{Z_{108}}$ have no elements of index nilpotence 4?

I know $r^4 = 0$, and the nilpotent elements must have factors of $3$ and $2$ in them but I can't seem to solve it?

Comment: The [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that any nilpotent elements will need to look like $2^j3^k$ for positive integers $j$ and $k$ such that $j<2$ or $k<3$.  Notice that, for any such integer (call it $x$), $108$ divides $x^3$.  Or in other words, $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{108}$.  So $4$ cannot be the least positive integer $k$ such that $x^k \equiv 0 \pmod{108}$.